# Toggle between themes with keyboard shortcut

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is is possible to assign a keyboard shortcut for switching between themes in VSCode?

I like Monokai or Monokai Seti for coding, but for writing documentation in Markdown I think light themes give better readability. I think this is because documentation text is mostly one color, whereas code is color highlighted for visibility.

To me it's most important to have a light theme for Markdown preview. It would be great if the MD preview pane could have a light theme while the actual MD code is Monokai or whatever.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is only the hotkey to trigger the theme selection drop down, nothing else (<kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> on macOS, <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> otherwise).

An alternative shortcut is <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> / <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>.

Comment: Thank you. I had hoped that I could assign a shortcut to a specific theme for speedy theme switching.

Comment: `alt + ctrl + T` opens Terminal in my Ubuntu Machine, how can I do same in Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: Added the alternative shortcut to the answer.

Answer (score 9):

There is an extension called "NightSwitch-Lite" that provides "Toggle Day/Night" command, then you could assign a keyboard shortcut to that command (i have it assigned to ScrollLock) to switch between light and dark themes.

Comment: I just came across this question via a Google search and this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: Seems to work only with the default dark and light themes, complains if you change them?

Answer (score 3):

**For people reading this in 2023**

[This is now included directly in VSCode!](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/main/release-notes/v1_69.md#toggle-between-light-and-dark-themes)

You can configure your preferred themes with the following settings:

- `workbench.preferredDarkColorTheme`
- `workbench.preferredLightColorTheme`
- `workbench.preferredHighContrastColorTheme`
- `workbench.preferredHighContrastLightColorTheme`

And switch with by opening the command palette with `Ctrl+Shift+P` and running `Preferences: Toggle between Light/Dark themes`.

You can also click on the small gear on the command to add a custom shortcut for it :)

Answer (score 2):

You can see the shortcut keys when you go to **File > Preferences > Color Theme (Ctrl+K Ctrl+T)** for Windows. I assume that for Mac it will be **Cmd+K Cmd+T**.

I see what you want to achieve [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f74dx.png), I was thinking the same thing today. May be if there is no way around it, we can submit a feature request on vscode's [github page](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=label%3Afeature-request%20).

Comment: That's exactly what I want.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a **VS Code extension** called [Toggle Light/Dark Theme](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=danielgjackson.auto-dark-mode-windows) by Daniel Jackson.

After installing the extension, click <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> (or, <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> in Mac OS) to toggle between the themes.

(Or, you can click on the small "circle divided in half" **icon** at the far-right corner of the VS Code status bar to perform the theme switch.)

---

**To customize the dark/light themes being used for the toggle:**

- Open **Settings** by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>, (comma)</kbd> (<kbd>command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>, (comma)</kbd> on Mac), or by

  - <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> on Mac), and type "Open User Settings"
- Type "Preferred **Dark** Color Theme" in the search and change from the dropdown. (I use "Dark Modern")
- Type "Preferred **Light** Color Theme" in the search and change from the dropdown. (I use "Light Modern")

Answer (score 0):

if using visual studio CODE - there is - it's by default <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>
But then if you're in the menu - you can use up and down arrows to preview them quickly without exiting the menu :) Hope this helps. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

There is a recent PR waiting to be merged https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/100861 that would, if accepted, add an argument to the `workbench.action.selectTheme` command.  Example from the PR:

```
   {
        "key": "ctrl+t ctrl+l",
        "command": "workbench.action.selectTheme",
        "args": {
            "id": "Default Light+"   // your light theme name here
        }
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+t ctrl+d",
        "command": "workbench.action.selectTheme",
        "args": {
            "id": "Default Dark+"   // your other theme name here
        }
    }
```

See [release notes: toggle between light and dark modes](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_69.md#toggle-between-lightdark-themes)